# Perform sidekiq job synchronously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

E.g. `SidekiqWorker` needs to be performed immediately instead of `SidekiqWorker.perform_async`.

How to perform (execute, run) sidekiq job (worker) synchronously (immediately, now, without a delay)?

Comment: Don't agree with the change of Brad Werth. Initially that was http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25931019/1 where I explained why I added this. But anyway you could downvote or close this if you think it's useless.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

```rb
SidekiqWorker.new.perform
```

Voila!

Comment: Is this somewhere in the docs?  I've been unable to find it so far, and need to sync up several jobs for my Cucumber tests.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JackM. e.g. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing#testing-workers-directly